# Implementing font installation in an iOS app to add a font to the device's font list

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native, fonts

I am developing an iOS app and I would like to have a functionality similar to iFont where, when the 'Install' button is pressed, the embedded font appears in the font list on my iPhone.

Can you provide information on how to achieve this? I am having difficulty finding relevant resources, so I am posting this question.

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/3227897-ctfontmanagerregisterfonturls

Comment: In my opinion, this function seems to be only usable within the app I'm developing. I want to add fonts to the iPhone system's font list itself. 

Just like the functionality in iFont, I want to be able to add the default provided fonts to the font list with a single install button

Comment: No, that is the function. You need to add the font entitlement to your provisioning profile and specify that you want the fonts you add to be persistent.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-custom-fonts